# Call ngAfterViewInit only after http call

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I have a requirement to load a javascript dynamically. I have to do this at the time of ngOnInit.

```
this._http.get(this.url + 'loadJS.js').map((response: Response) =>response.text())
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.loadModule(data);
    }, 
    (error) => {
      console.log('failed to load...');
    });`
```

but the problem is that this http call takes time and meanwhile the ngAfterViewInit is called. and my javascript fails to load, so the template throws error that the JS is not found. How can I delay the ngAfterViewInit or call ngAfterViewInit only after the successful http call

Comment: "and my code fails" what fails ? what are the errors ?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: you can't because these hooks related to change detection, not data initialization

Comment: Use `subject.next()` in response and `subject.subscribe` in ngAfterViewInit